# Возвращения значения с функции по ссылке и по rvalue ссылке

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки

Когда мы возвращаем объект из функции по ссылке, тогда у нас вызывается конструктор копирования.

```
Top& GetRef()
{
   Top top(args);
   return top;
}

int main()
{
   Top top = GetRef();
   std::cout << top.property << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Вопрос. Можно ли заменить возвращение с функции по ссылке на `std::move()` или точнее, на возвращение по `rvalue` ссылку и будет ли это правильным? Будет ли такое изменение считаться более экономным чем вызов конструктора копирования?

```
Top&& GetRef()
{
   Top top(args);
   return std::move(top);
}

int main()
{
   Top&& top = GetRef();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неправильно и то, и другое - поскольку возвращает ссылку на локальную переменную, которая по выходу из функции уничтожается.

Правильное решение -

```
Top GetRef()
{
   Top top(args);
   return top;
}
```

Остальное сделает за вас компилятор. И семантику перемещения, и оптимизацию, так, что даже создавать объект `top` будет прямо в объекте, которому присвоите результат вызова функции...

"Корень всех зол - в преждевременной оптимизации" (с) Кнут

Глядя на возврат ссылки на локальную переменную, я бы добавил - "и в непонимании фундаментальных вещей, о которых просто кричит компилятор" :) Думаю, он вас честно предупреждал, что вы делаете что-то не то...

Comment: makes sense! проблема в том, что я это как бы и знал, но сам себя запутал тем, что у меня вызвался конструктор копирования, а сделать шаг дальше по стеку вызова я не додумался. спасибо.